# Proving Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

If there is a function g such that $$g(x,y,z)=x^3f(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$$. How would one prove that $$x(\partial g/\partial x)+y(\partial g/\partial y)+z(\partial g/\partial z)=3g $$

I tried using chain rule in many ways but did not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x,y,z)=x^3f(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}), \text{ and denote positions of } f \text{ as } a,b, \text{ i.e. } f(a,b)$$

$$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y,z)=x(3x^2f(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})+x^3(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\cdot(-\frac{y}{x^2})+\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot(-\frac{z}{x^2})))$$
$$=3x^3f(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})-x^2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}-x^2z\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=3g-x^2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}-x^2z\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\text{ (1) }$$

$$y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y,z)=yx^3(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\cdot\frac{1}{x})=x^2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} \text{ (2) }$$

$$z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}g(x,y,z)=zx^3(\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cdot\frac{1}{x})=x^2z\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} \text{ (3) }$$

Add (1),(2),(3) together, and you get what you want.